# Closures with Javascript callbacks

Tags: javascript, closures

I thought I understood closures well with Javascript, but apparently I don't.  The following code doesn't work.  How do I get it to print out all the numbers from 0 through 9 in the console after a 1 second delay?  Currently it just prints "undefined" ten times.

NOTE:  I'm not looking for a simpler workout to printing out numbers after a delay.  This question is about understanding closures.

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(function(i){console.log(i)}, 1000)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures are important in JavaScript, but it is important to understand what exactly you are `closing` over. To rework your current code (kind of).

```
function(){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(i);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

In this example, your code is basically closing over `var i;`, which means that when the timer runs, it will read the value of `var i;` and print that out. In this case, as you have seen, when the timer runs, the loop has finished and the value is `10`.

What you want to do is create a new function scope that captures the value of `i` at a specific time.

```
function(){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        (function(iInner){
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(iInner);
            }, 1000);
        })(i);
    }
}
```

This example will create a new anonymous function, and then calling it immediately in the loop, and pass the current value of `i` into it, so that when your timer reads `iInner`, it will read the value that was passed into the function, rather than the value from `var i;`. You can also just call `iInner` `i` if you want, but I've used two different names for clarity.

There are also helpers that you can use, like `.bind` that will essentially automatically create a new anonymous function for you, and pass in arguments like this.

```
function(){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        setTimeout(function(iInner){
            console.log(iInner);
        }.bind(null, i), 1000);
    }
}
```

`<func>.bind` will take the value of `i` and return a new function that passes those args through to `<func>` when called, and you avoid having to create another layer of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the callback function to take parameter `i`, which is masking the closurable `i` declared in the for loop. So change it to:

```
<script>
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    setTimeout(function(){console.log(i)}, 1000)
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I wasn't looking at the general intention of your question. In terms of the way closures work, the function object captures a reference to any variable in the enclosing scope that is referred to from inside the function body, and which does not bind to any local variable (parameter or explicit `var` declaration) inside the body. That's why your original attempt didn't work; the `i` was binding to the local parameter.

The function object does *not* capture the *value* that the closured variable possessed at the time the function was defined; it captures a *reference* to it. Thus, you can't iterate a single variable (I'm talking about the `var i` declared in the for loop) with the intention that the *value* be closured for each subsequent function definition. Values aren't closured; variables are.

But, you *can* effectively closure a value by closuring on a temporary local that has the value you want to capture at the time you define the function. It requires creating a new function scope and defining the closuring function inside that scope, closuring around a local (function parameter) that has the value you want:

```
<script>
for (var i_outer = 0; i_outer < 10; ++i_outer)
    setTimeout((function(i_inner) { return function() { console.log(i_inner); }; })(i_outer), 1000 );
</script>
```

Comment: Nope!  That just prints `10` ten times.  That's why we need closures.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it. You create a IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression), that returns a function that prints to console. Remember the value of i, should be swallowed by the inner function, by passing it as an argument.

setTimeout expects a "function" as a first argument and that's the reason we return a function from the IIFE.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() {
            console.log(i);
        }
    })(i), 1000)
}
```

Thanks